# "Analogue" of dominated convergence theorem for non integrable functions

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a measure on some measure space and $f,f_1,f_2,\dots$ be non-negative functions such that $f_n\nearrow f,\ \int f_n d\mu<\infty\ \forall n$ and $\int f d\mu=\infty$. Is it true that $\lim_n \int f_n d\mu=\infty$? If it is not true in general, at least does it  hold when $\mu$ is finite? If it is the case, that would be useful to solve a probability theory exercise I'm stuck on.

Comment: Have you come across Monotone Convergence Theorem?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the desired conclusion is true under the stated assumptions for an arbitrary measure, even if the limiting integral is infinite. This is a result known as the [monotone convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Theorem_3).

Comment: Maybe not immediately relevant for the OP, but the theorem also holds if the $f_n$ and $f$ are allowed to assume $+\infty$ as a value, i.e. the codomains are $[0,\infty]$.